# Organizing files into folders based on filename

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a program that reads pdf files (e.g files.pdf), separates them by name and moves them to their relevant folder (based on name), like this:

```
Files:
house.pdf
house_blue.pdf
road.pdf

Folders:
house = house.pdf, house_blue.pdf
road  = road.pdf
```

My code by now:

```
for f in os.listdir():
    file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    if len(file_name.split('_')) == 2:
        f_name, f_course = file_name.split('_')
    elif len(file_name.split('_')) != 2:
        f_name = file_name

def movefile (file_name):
    new_dir =  src + "/" + file_name
    for file_name in os.listdir():
        if not os.path.exists(new_dir):
            os.mkdir(new_dir)
        if file_name.startswith(file_name):
            shutil.move(src+"/"+file_name, new_dir)
```

It's working fine, the only problem is that the for statement is resulting in only the last pdf file, creating only one folder and copying all files to that folder.

Can someone help me where it is wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Code Working:

```
src = (os.getcwd())

for f in os.walk(src):
    for f in os.listdir(src):
        if os.path.isfile(src): #Checar se possui arquivos dentro da   pasta(src).
            continue
        lfolders = os.listdir(src) #Atribuir na variavel lfolders todos os diretórios na pasta (src).
        file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(f) #separar nome da extensão (.pdf)
        if len(file_name.split('_')) == 2: #se possuir dois nomes (nome e curso)
            f_name, f_course = file_name.split('_')
            try:
                if f_name not in lfolders:
                    for dirmake in os.listdir(src):
                        os.makedirs(os.path.join(src, f_name))
                elif f_name in lfolders:
                    shutil.move(f, src+"/"+f_name)
            except OSError:
                pass

        elif len(file_name.split(')')) != 2: #se possuir um nome (nome)
            f_name = file_name
            try:
                if f_name not in lfolders:
                    for dirmake in os.listdir(src):
                        os.makedirs(os.path.join(src, f_name))
                elif f_name in lfolders:
                    shutil.move(f, src+"/"+f_name)
            except OSError:
                pass
```

Comment: improves the indentation of your code, in python it is very important

Comment: Bad formating at stackoverflow, sorry for that.

Comment: Well, you're not doing anything within the loop except assigning values, so what did you expect?

Comment: By the way, you might want to look at using something like `glob(*.pdf)` rather than just `listdir`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to *do something* for every iteration of the loop.

```
for f in os.listdir():
    file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    if file_ext == 'pdf':
        if len(file_name.split('_')) == 2:
            folder, f_course = file_name.split('_')
        elif len(file_name.split('_')) != 2:
            folder = file_name
    print("Ready to move {} into folder {}".format(file_name, folder)) 
    movefile(f, folder)  # Call your function, add a parameter for the folder
```

Comment: I trying that, but maybe I'm doing something wrong. 
I tried also to .append the result of the loop on a list, but when I try to create folders from that I'm getting errors or no result.

Comment: Are you recreating a list within the loop, or only creating a single list outside of it?

Comment: Now it worked, I`m going to edit the post. I would like now to implement the same code for subfoulders. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please submit a new post rather than edit the original